# .htaccess doesn't allow me to contack

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello my friend i am working on captcha validation but i can not get example page when i created

this is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

and this is my example.php file which is in views folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.refreshCaptcha').on('click', function () {
                $.get('<?php echo base_url().'captcha / refresh'; ?>', function (data) {
                    $('#captImg').html(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h4>Submit Captcha Code</h4>
    <p id="captImg">
        <?php echo $captchaImg; ?>
    </p>
    <p>Can't read the image? click
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="refreshCaptcha">here</a> to refresh.</p>
    <form method="post">
        Enter the code :
        <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

but when i wire localhost/capcode/example, it shows foo:bar how can i fix this?